# Phpunit не работает при запуске c консоли, а с Phpstorm все ок

Tags: php, phpunit

Phpunit не работает при запуске c консоли

```
phpunit --bootstrap tests/bin/bootstrap.php tests
```

Выводит:

`PHP Warning:  require_once(../../host.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/auna/docker-web-stack/htdocs/brt-site/tests/bin/bootstrap.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../host.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/auna/docker-web-stack/htdocs/brt-site/tests/bin/bootstrap.php on line 3`ё

где bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
define('PHPUNIT_IS_RUN', true);
require_once '../../host.php';
```

host.php лежит в корне проекта

Если запустить тест с Phpstorm, где edit configuration стоит directory в папку tests, то все норм. Не работает также, если подключать конфиг файл и запустить со шторма. Ошибка та же. Этот файл лежит в корне проекта и выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="/tests/bin/bootstrap.php" colors="true">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="testSuite">
        <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Почему не находит host.php?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, в чем была проблема. Но решение простое:
заметить

```
require_once '../../host.php';
```

на

```
require_once  ____DIR___.'/../../host.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Знаю что проблема решена, хотел объяснить почему не работало.

При запуске из консоли,  путь считается относительно папки в которой набранна команда.

т.е.

`/home/user/folder> php lib/test/file.php`

```
<?php
    // file.php
    require "../../test.php";
```

будет подключать файл:

`/home/test.php`

Поэтому с относительным  путям  над  аккуратно. прописыват их надо относительно  файла.

`/home/user/folder> php lib/test/file.php`

```
<?php
    // file.php
    require __DIR__ . "/../../test.php";
```

будет подключать файл:

`/home/user/folder/test.php`